# Using a maven project to test another project

Tags: java, maven, junit, dependencies, project

I have to do the following:

- Create a project "A" in maven.
- Create another project "B" which contains the JUnit tests for "A"
- add maven dependencies so that B is used to test A

There are many resources out there which describe how to add test to an existing project but I didn't realy found a way to add another project for the unit tests.

Here is what I had in mind:

**Project A**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Project B (Test)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Unit Test** (Placeholder)

```java
package group.B;

import org.junit.*;
import group.A.aClass;


public class aClassTest {

    @Test 
    void testTest() {
        assert(false);  // this should fail, right?
    }
}
```

I am using Netbeans with the Maven plugin, just so you know. Both projects now each other, the dependencies are fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK. What's your problem? Do you have any unit tests in Project B? Do you have any problem running them?

Comment: I will add the test file. I don't know how to run them,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above produces a circular dependency.

I have done this in the past not for unit tests but for integration tests. What I suggest is that B depends on A (A has no dependency on B). In `src/test/java` of `B` write all the tests you need. When you run `mvn test` on B it will pass or fail depending on if the tests pass or fail. There is not a way to make the compilation of `A` fail based on the tests in `B`.

Comment: I thought that it is strange that maven or netbeans didn't complained about the circular dependency so I thought it is fine with maven. ;)
After I changed it, it works fine. Thanks for the hint.